# To set values to all the form elments using Data binding and SET method in Total js in a single go

Tags: total.js

This is what iam doing currently. But i want to do it in a single statement.

```
            SET('perDetails.form.fname', document['myData']['fname']);
            SET('perDetails.form.lname', document['myData']['lname']);
            SET('perDetails.form.age', document['myData']['age']);
            SET('perDetails.form.height', document['myData']['height']);
            SET('perDetails.form.bday', document['myData']['bday']);
            SET('perDetails.form.email1', document['myData']['email1']);
            SET('perDetails.form.phoneNo', document['myData']['phoneNo']);
            SET('perDetails.form.message', document['myData']['message']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform:

```js
EXTEND('perDetails.form', document.myData);
```